# How to work with dropdown in formarray in Angular?

Tags: angular

[image]Here I am trying to dynamically select the dropdown value but the issue I am facing is when I am selecting value in dropdown I am getting object out of it and from it I am trying to set the value of unitprice in unitprice field , but it is getting set in every unit price field, Generally It should be for particular index .
Any sort of help is appreciated

```
         <form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
                      <div formArrayName="arr" *ngFor="let a of myForm.get('arr').controls; let i = index">
                        <div [formGroupName]="i" style="margin-bottom: 10px;" class="form-inline">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                              <label>ProdName :</label>
                              <select name="productnames" formControlName="productnames" id="productnames"
                                class="form-control form-control-element" 
                               >
                                <option *ngFor="let catalog of productlist" [ngValue]="catalog">
                                  {{catalog.productname}}
                                </option>
                              </select>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                       </div>
                      </div>
margin: 0 inherit;" />
  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                      <label>UnitPrice :</label>
                      <input type="text" name="unitprices" size="10" value="{{unitprices}}" formControlName="unitprices">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
     <input type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg active" (click)="onSubmit()"
                  value="AddElement" style="text-align: center;
```

TsFile:-

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      arr: this.fb.array([this.createItem()])
    })
    this.getallproductname(event)
  }

 getallproductname(event) {
    const base_URL = 'http://localhost:9007/api/excel/getAllList'
    this.http.get(base_URL,).subscribe(data => {
      this.productlist.push(data)
      this.productlist = this.productlist[0]
    
    })

createItem() {
    return this.fb.group({
      quantities: [''],
      unitprices: [''] ,
      totalprices:[''],
      productnames:['']
    })
  }

 onSubmit() {
   
    console.log(this.myForm.value);
  }
```

returnedObject :-

```
 {
          "productid": 1,
          "productname": "RO",
          "imagepath": "./assets/1.jpeg",
          "unitprice": "4000",
          "productdescription": "Faber FWP Galaxy PRO Reverse Osmosis Water Purifier 7L, black, ro+mat",
          "warrantydays": "90",
          "totalamount": 0,
          "quantity": 3
        }
```

Comment: is it possible to share the working code like on stackblitz?

Comment: Added Image for more Information , pls check

Comment: in `<select>` tag you have added both `formControlName="productnames"` or `[(ngModel)]="productnames"` . remove the`[(ngModel)]="productnames"` and then try it.

Comment: @neilnikkunilesh , added

Comment: is it working now?

Answer (score 0):

If your using `formControlName` in the formArray then no need to use `ngmodel`.
It will bind with all the form component and syncs with same variable that you use in `.ts` file.

> `[(ngmodel)]` accepts a domain model as an optional Input. If you have a one-way binding to ngModel with [] syntax, changing the domain model's value in the component class sets the value in the view. If you have a two-way binding with [()] syntax (also known as 'banana-in-a-box syntax'), the value in the UI always syncs back to the domain model in your class

In your case for `<select>` tag you have added both `formControlName="productnames"` or `[(ngModel)]="productnames"`.
Remove the[(ngModel)]="productnames".

Comment: In case of unit price which is coming from dropdown how to fix that @neilnikkunilesh

Answer (score 0):

When we write some like:

```
<select name="productnames" formControlName="productnames">
   <option *ngFor="let catalog of productlist" [ngValue]="catalog">
      {{catalog.productname}}
   </option>
</select>
```

in your formControl "productnames" really you has an full object -the calagod selected-. The reason is that your're write `[ngValue]="catalog"`, NOT, e.g. `[ngValue]="catalog.productid"`

Yes a FormControl can store a whole object. This can be convenience. In this case I fell that it's the best option

So we can has a input readonly with

```
<input readonly [value]="myForm.get('arr').value[i].unitprices"> //(*)
```

And another like

```
<input readonly [value]="(+myForm.get('arr').value[i].unitprices)*
                 (+myForm.get('arr').value[i].quantities)"> //(*)
```

See that the input is not a "formControl", has no `formControlName`or `[formControl]` and the elements of your formArray really are very different to you expect. Really your items should be like:

```
createItem() {
    return this.fb.group({
      productnames:['']
      quantities: [''],
    })
  }
```

And one element will be like,e.g.

```
{
   productnames:{
      "productid": 1,
      "productname": "RO",
      "imagepath": "./assets/1.jpeg",
      "unitprice": "4000",
      "quantity":3,
      ....
   },
   quantities:20,
}
```

Well, it's true that, before send the data to de service we need create an object using the `myForm.value`

NOTE: usually, only for check we write in our .html some like

```
<pre>
{{myForm.value|json}}
</pre>
```

(*) really always that we want to work with FormArrays we should use a getter

```
get catalogFormArray()
{
    return this.myForm.get('arr') as FormArray
}
```

And use

```
<input readonly [value]="catalogFormArray.value[i].unitprices">

<input readonly [value]="(+catalogFormArray.value[i].unitprices)*
                 (+catalogFormArray.value[i].quantities)">
```